# jQuery Mobile dialog opens incorrectly in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-dialog

I have problem with jQuery Mobile dialog. When is the page first time loaded (after JQM init) and after that when I click on dialog button (*open dialog*), *dialog* is opened incorrectly. Instead of include into DOM, is dialog page opened as a new page.  Thats happend **only in Safari browser**. Have anyone same problem, or any idea how to fix it? Thank you.

**index.html**

```html
...
    <div>
        <a href="dialog.html" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">open dialog</a>
    </div>
...
```

**dialog.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Přidat rezervaci</title>
    <body> 
      <div data-role="page" id="reservation-form" data-close-btn="right" data-history="false">
         <!-- some next code -->
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**jQuery Mobile configuration:**

```js
$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 70;
$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold  = 40;
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.useFastClick = true;
```

*jQuery version: 1.9.1
jQuery mobile version: 1.3.1*

Here is the preview:

[image]

Comment: _"page is opened incorrectly"_ - in what way?

Comment: Thanks for answar. Thats means: when I click on "open dialog" button, the dialog is opened as a new page, insteat of insert into DOM and should be shown as the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It was cause by `<audio>` element hack for mobile devices.

```
$(document).one("click", "body", function(){
 play(true);
 return false;
});

function play(first){
var a =  $("#audio");
if(a.length !== 0){
    a = a[0];
    if(first){
        a.currentTime=a.duration-.01;
        a.play();
        a.load();
    }else{
        a.play();
    }
}
return false;
}
```